# Can I use Flex 4.5 to package application on iOS on Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, flex4.5

I am using Flex 4.5 for mobile development on Windows. I want to package my application for iOS but I don't have a MAC. Is this possible from windows?

Please help!

Regards,
Sanket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is possible to do mobile development with Flex 4.5 even if you are a Windows user. You don't need a Mac but you will need *two* files: a **code-signing certificate** and **provisioning profile**.

If you take a look  at the Flex Build Packaging-Dialog under the project properties you will see that these two files have to being targeted for iOS:

[image: Flash Builder 4.5.1 Flex Build Packaging-Dialog]

You obtain those files from Apple. But first you have to *register as an Apple Developer* here:

http://developer.apple.com/programs/register

To complete the registration you have to pay 99$/year. After successful registration you will receive an activation mail. After that you are able to start the setup of your certificates, devices and profiles in the *[Apple iOS Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action)*.

The Apple Developer Center will walk you through all the necessary steps:

[image: Apple Development Provisioning Assistant]

There are some additional steps to get that all working on Windows, because you will have to generate and convert certificates. For that I'm using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) (a Linux-like environment for Windows). Be sure to include the **OpenSSL** packages during installation!

Once installed, follow the Adobe documentation: [Obtaining developer files from Apple](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b2-240138de1243a7725e7-7ffd.html).

I'm sure that the following articles will also a good help for you:

- [Flex/AIR for iOS Development Process Explained](http://devgirl.org/2011/06/20/flexair-for-ios-development-process-explained/)
- [iPhone Development on Windows](http://maniacdev.com/2010/01/iphone-development-windows-options-available/)

Regards,
Christian

Comment: Christian, Thanks a lot! I never expected such a detailed answer.